# How to handle errors occurring during the processing of data in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am writing a Java application using **Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams**. Here is the functional method snippet I'm using:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> process() {
    return input ->
        input.transform(
            () ->
                new Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>>() {

                  ProcessorContext context;

                  @Override
                  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                    this.context = context;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void close() {}

                  @Override
                  public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {                       
                         String result = fetch_data_from_database(key, value);
                         return new KeyValue<>(key, result);
                  }
});
```

**fetch_data_from_database()** can throw an Exception.

How can I stop the processing of the inbound KStream(offset should not get committed) in case of exception from fetch_from_database() and make it retry processing with the same offset data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299528/handling-exceptions-in-kafka-streams This question is also raising same concern but the answer provided doesn't tell how to deal with Processing exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to retry the logic on your own. For that, you can use Spring's `RetryTemplate`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62180518/2070861) has the details about how to use the `RetryTemplate` within Kafka Streams. It does not use the low-level Processor API as you have, but it's the same idea. Wrap your database call within a retry template and customize the retries based on your requirements. Any upstream processing will be paused until the retries are exhausted.

Comment: The RetryTemplate exists outside of the kafka processing so if you keep retrying longer than the poll time a kafka consumer rebalance will occur.